# No symbols have been loaded for this document. Breakpoint issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I already had a look at solutions on the internet for this problem but no one really worked.

What I already tried:

- Cleaning the solution and rebuilding everything
- Deleteing the bin + obj directory
- Restarting visual studio
- Restarting the pc
- Loading the module manually (but it will not be loaded when starting debugging again so this is a really annoying solution)

I have two startup projects, one is loaded normally but the other one is not.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What more information do you expect? I described the whole problem...

Comment: What do you mean two startup projects? You switch between them and then one of them does not allow you to place active breakpoints? You should really be more clear as to what exactly the problem is, and what you are seeing as opposed to what you expect to see.

Comment: Well I have two startup projects starting at the same time when I start debugging. Breakpoints I set only work in one of both projects so I just can debug one project properly.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this by deactivating the option "Optimize code" in project properties.